# Process with symfony5, ffmpeg

Tags: shell, command-line, ffmpeg, symfony5

I was using this code to execute commands with symfony3

```
$cl = 'ffmpeg -i "path/file.mp4"  -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn  "path/file.mp3"';
$process = new Process($cl);
$process->run();
```

It worked perfectly on symfony3.
Now i have migrated my site to symfony5. this code no longer works.
I understood that "$cl" must be an array but i still don't understand
the order of parameters and options with the ffmpeg command

Comment: split the $cl at every space (removing the extra one before -f and after -vn) and it probably might work ...

Comment: See this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html and customize in your convenient